# Dropdown List in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

In My view page ,

```
    $cpfTabledropdown = ManageConfiguration::getModulesetting();
    echo $form->dropdownList($useraccount, 'skill_type', $cpfTabledropdown, array('class' => 'form-control', 'prompt' => 'Select SKill Type', 'disabled' => $useraccount->id_type == 3 ? false : true));
```

In My Model Coding:

```
public static function getModulesetting() {
    $models = HrmoduleSettings::model()->findAll('type="6"');
    return CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'name');
 }
```

Now am want that return listdata in name concat some static data using  column subcat ,How to concat that static data in that return name value in yii Like below PHP coding,

I want to show Dropdownlist data like Below PHP coding in YII.Its Php Coding its working Fine,But I don't know how to write in YII.IS it possible to write the below PHP coding in YII?

```
<select name ="UserAccount[skill_type]">
  <?php
    foreach ($cpfTabledropdown as $models) {
     if ($models->subcat_type == 1) 
         {
       $cate = "Skilled";
         } 
       else {
         $cate = "Unskilled";
         }
        ?>
        <option value ="<?php echo $models->id; ?>"><?php echo $cate . " " . $models->name; ?></option>
     <?php
       }
       ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a new version of the getModuleSetting function to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
public static function getModulesetting() {
   $models = HrmoduleSettings::model()->findAll('type="6"');
   return CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 
           function($models) {
             $cate = "What Ever"; // $cate content
             return $cate . ' ' . $models->name; 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter in your `HrmoduleSettings` class, so you can avoid adding code related to data in the view.

Add the following method in your `HrmoduleSettings` class:

```
public function getNameWithCategory()
{
    if ($this->subcat_type == 1)
        return "Skilled " . $this->name;
    else
        return "Unskilled " . $this->name;
}
```

Now you have to make a little change to your `CHtml::listData()` call:

```
CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'nameWithCategory');
```

And that's it!